# Mime type bmp файла распознается как png  (PHP)

Tags: gd, изображения, php, mime, fileupload

Mime type bmp файла распознается как png, делаю проверку через getimagesize.

В результате не получается задействовать безопасную загрузку. Как такое решается?

Answer (score 1):

Не претендую на истинность, но поделюсь своим опытом в данном деле. Хочу сразу оговориться, что наверняка есть и более продвинутые способы.

В общем, у [.bmp-файла](http://open-file.ru/types/bmp) стандартный заголовок

```
42 4D
```

Как видите, длина всего 2 байта. В PHP есть функция [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php), которая позволяет прочитать содержимое файла в строку с заданными маркерами смещения. То есть можно написать такой код:

```
$filename   = "путь_до_файла.bmp";
$fileheader = file_get_contents($filename, NULL, NULL, 0, 2); //читаем первые 2 байта от начала файла.
```

И в переменной `$fileheader` у вас будут первые 2 байта файла, т.е. заголовок файла.

Далее производим простую проверку:

```
  if($fileheader == "BM"){ //BM - ASCII представление шестнадцатиричного числа.
    echo "Настоящий .bmp файл";
  } else {
    echo "Не настоящий .bmp файл";
  }
```

Вот как-то так. :)

Comment: ого а как такое для всех файлов расписать? Есть туториал готовый?

Comment: то есть png,gif,jpg

Comment: Вспомнил, что уже давал ответ на похожий вопрос. В общем читайте [Mime тип из названия файла или расширения][1], там человек приводил ссылку на готовый скрипт.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/128501/php-mime-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=128573#128573

Comment: Почитал немного документацию по php, дабы обновить свои данные и вот что выяснил. Оказывается, ещё с версии 5.3, в состав PHP включено расширение [fileinfo][1], которое отвечает за корректное определение MIME-тип файла.

  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.fileinfo.php